# How can I cancel an up-vote or down-vote?

Tags: bug, voting

I inadvertently up-voted the wrong answer (it happened because of scrolling). The answer now had a total of 1 vote (mine). To cancel my upvote, I clicked down-vote. Unexpectedly the question now had a score of minus one. I don't want this either because the answer isn't so bad that I want to penalise it.

This is very peculiar maths.

1 - 1 = -1

and

-1 + 1 = 1

Why can't I simply do what I want to do and cancel my vote?

Comment: It is more likely that someone else downvoted the answer at the same time that you retracted your upvote.  It doesn't show timing but you can look at the total number of up and down votes (with enough rep, which you have) by clicking the number of votes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To retract an upvote or a downvote, just click within 5 minutes from the previous vote the same vote button. This will retract the vote.

Past the 5 minutes the vote is locked and can be changed only upon edit of the voted post.

Comment: Ah - I see, a non-intuitive interface! 1 + 1 = 0 ....Thanks, now I know.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK more like an on-off switch on the vote, I think.

Comment: @Renan Yes. Undoing the vote doesn't register an opposite vote; it *undoes* the vote (and reverses the reputation gain/cost for both voter and votee).